# python3 insert in a text words at specific position

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text and I would like to be able to add certain words to a specific position in it. To do this, I need to cut my text into letters (not words). I can do the work but the problem is that the word I want to add cuts off another word.

My input( the numbers are not good because the text is much longer but this way you get an idea)  :
{”text":The applicant's cells were overcrowded. The detainees had to take turns to sleep because there was usually one sleeping place for two to three of them. There was almost no light in the cells because of the metal shutters on the windows, as well as no fresh air. The lack of air was aggravated by the detainees' smoking and the applicant, a non-smoker, became a passive smoker. There was one hour of daily exercise. The applicant's eyesight deteriorated and he developed respiratory problems. In summer the average air temperature was around thirty degrees which, combined with the high humidity level, caused skin conditions to develop. The sanitary conditions were below any reasonable standard. In particular, the cells were supplied with water for only one or two hours a day and on some days there was no water supply at all. The lack of water caused intestinal problems and in 1999 the administration had to announce quarantine in that connection. ,"label":[[328,347,"Article 3 - Violated"],[2269,2323,"Article 3 - Violated"],[2791,2843,"Article 3 - Violated"],[2947,2988,"Article 3 - Violated"],[3099,3110,"Article 3 - Violated"],[3603,3615,"Article 3 - Violated"],[3702,3756,"Article 3 - Violated"],[4793,4923,"Article 3 - Violated"],[5185,5196,"Article 3 - Violated"],[8111,8198,"Article 3 - Respected"],[8510,8521,"Article 3 - Respected"],[8575,8601,"Article 3 - Respected"],[8965,9009,"Article 3 - Respected"],

And I would like to have this:

The applicant's cells were overcrowded. The detainees had to take turns to sleep because there was usually one sleeping place for two to three of them. There was almost no light in the cells because of the metal shutters on the windows, as well as no fresh air. The lack of air was aggravated by the detainees' smoking and the applicant, a non-smoker, became a passive smoker. There was one hour of daily exercise. The applicant's eyesight deteriorated and he developed respiratory problems. In summer the average air temperature was around thirty degrees which, combined with the high humidity level, caused skin conditions to develop. **<Article 3 - Violated>The sanitary conditions were below any reasonable standard</Article 3 - Violated>.** In particular, the cells were supplied with water for only one or two hours a day and on some days there was no water supply at all. The lack of water caused intestinal problems and in 1999 the administration had to announce quarantine in that connection.

but I get this. It cuts the words.

3. The applicant's cells were overcrowded. The detainees had to take turns to sleep because there was usually one sleeping place for two to three of them. There was almost no light in the cells because of the metal shutters on the windows, as well as no fresh air. The lack of air was aggravated by the detainees' smoking and the applicant, a non-smoker, became a passive smoker. There was one hour of daily exercise. The applicant's eyesight deteriorated and he developed respiratory problems. In summer the average air temperature was around thirty degrees which, combined with the high humidity level, caused skin conditions to develop. **<Article 3 - Violated>The sanitary conditions were below any reasonable stan <Article 3 - Violated/>dard**. In particular, the cells were supplied with water for only one or two hours a day and on some days there was no water supply at all. The lack of water caused intestinal problems and in 1999 the administration had to announce quarantine in that connection.

My code:

```
text =list(texte["text"].strip())
label = texte["label"]
for i in label:
    debut = i[0]
    fin = i[1]
    nom = i[2]
    for element in range(len(text)):
        if element == debut:
            text.insert(element,"<"+nom+">")
        if element == fin:
            a = element +1
            text.insert(element+1,"<"+nom+"/>")
string = ""
for element in  text:
    string += element
print(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems a bit odd: (1) Why are you making a character list out of the string? (2) The looping here `for element in range(len(text)): ...` seems completely unnecessary, why are you not directly using `debut` and `fin`?

**Problem** of your approach: By inserting items to the list `text` the position numbers in the label-lists become invalid.

Here's an **alternative approach**. I'm using the following data as a sample:

```
texte = {
    "text": "The applicant's cells were overcrowded. The detainees had to take turns to sleep because there was usually one sleeping place for two to three of them. There was almost no light in the cells because of the metal shutters on the windows, as well as no fresh air. The lack of air was aggravated by the detainees' smoking and the applicant, a non-smoker, became a passive smoker. There was one hour of daily exercise. The applicant's eyesight deteriorated and he developed respiratory problems. In summer the average air temperature was around thirty degrees which, combined with the high humidity level, caused skin conditions to develop. The sanitary conditions were below any reasonable standard. In particular, the cells were supplied with water for only one or two hours a day and on some days there was no water supply at all. The lack of water caused intestinal problems and in 1999 the administration had to announce quarantine in that connection.",
    "label": [[262, 375, "Article 3 - Violated"], [637, 695, "Article 3 - Violated"]]
}
```

The numbers in `texte["label"]` mark the start and end of the following two passages:

> The lack of air was aggravated by the detainees' smoking and the applicant, a non-smoker, became a passive smoker.

> The sanitary conditions were below any reasonable standard.

The first number in a label-list is the position of the start of the passage, the second number is the first position *after* the last character of the passage. But I'm not sure about that, I haven't seen any related information in the question.

Now this

```
text = texte["text"]
new_text = ""
last_fin = 0
for debut, fin, nom in texte["label"]:
    new_text +=  text[last_fin:debut] + "<" + nom + ">" + text[debut:fin] + "<" + nom + "/>"
    last_fin = fin
new_text += text[last_fin:]
```

results in the following `new_text`:

> The applicant's cells were overcrowded. The detainees had to take turns to sleep because there was usually one sleeping place for two to three of them. There was almost no light in the cells because of the metal shutters on the windows, as well as no fresh air. **<Article 3 - Violated>The lack of air was aggravated by the detainees' smoking and the applicant, a non-smoker, became a passive smoker.<Article 3 - Violated/>** There was one hour of daily exercise. The applicant's eyesight deteriorated and he developed respiratory problems. In summer the average air temperature was around thirty degrees which, combined with the high humidity level, caused skin conditions to develop. **<Article 3 - Violated>The sanitary conditions were below any reasonable standard.<Article 3 - Violated/>** In particular, the cells were supplied with water for only one or two hours a day and on some days there was no water supply at all. The lack of water caused intestinal problems and in 1999 the administration had to announce quarantine in that connection.

If the second number in a label-list is the position of the last character of the passage (instead of the position of the first character after the passage), then the following should produce the same `nex_text`:

```
text = texte["text"]
new_text = ""
last_fin = 0
for debut, fin, nom in texte["label"]:
    fin += 1
    new_text += text[last_fin:debut] + "<" + nom + ">" + text[debut:fin] + "<" + nom + "/>"
    last_fin = fin
new_text += text[last_fin:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! In fact, I used an annotation tool that gave me the information according to the position of the characters and not the strings so that's why I have this constraint. 

Otherwise, you guessed it right, the first number corresponds to the start position and the second number corresponds to the exit position. 

I tried your code but I still have the same problem as I had at the beginning i.e. it cuts the words because the position of the characters change since I change the list by adding words.

Comment: @Evarln I really don't understand why you have to use the `list`-approach :) What exactly is keeping you from doing something like I've suggested? As long as the numbers in the label-lists in `texte["labels"]` are in sync with the `texte["text"]` pieces of text I don't see a reason not to do that?

Comment: No, you are right about your approach. I was just explaining why at first I thought that doing it this way seemed like a good approach but yours is more intelligent and cleaner. However, I still have the same problem

Comment: @Evarln Ah, I see. But then I've either missed some crucial part of the picture or you are hiding it :)

Comment: Indeed, I can't put all my input :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use .replace method;

```
string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)
```

In your case you can replace "applicant's" string with:

```
text.replace("applicant's" , "Name", count_that_times_you_want_to_replace)
```

Can find more info here ;
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know replace but I don't see how it can help me? My problem is that when I cut the string into characters, the "'s" is considered as two characters, but I would like it to be considered as one character so that I don't cut the words when I insert. Because the problem is that I have the positions of the characters from another file that doesn't seem to split the strings like I do, so it's a mismatch.

Comment: Hi Evarln I thought you were trying to replace a certain string with an another certain. If you can put whole script in your post can try to achiev what you plan to do. You can also use replace() method at first text you are getting to remove single quotation marks.

Comment: Yes, I think I did not express myself well :-) I tried to do it better by editing my post, thanks!